# Heroku webpacker with assets on s3 - asset not found in manifesst

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, webpack, webpacker

I deployed a rails 6 app with webpacker on heroku.
The public/packs are sync to an s3 bucket, same as the public/assets. 
Delivering assets from public/assets works. But when trying to open anything dependent on public/packs I get.

```
2020-06-04T05:33:03.622234+00:00 app[web.1]: [58f2d221-761b-44ec-807c-6b922342c10b] method=GET path=/teach/organizations format=html controller=OrganizationsController action=index status=500 error='ActionView::Template::Error: Webpacker can't find admin_unify_style.css in /app/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
2020-06-04T05:33:03.622242+00:00 app[web.1]: 1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
2020-06-04T05:33:03.622242+00:00 app[web.1]: unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2020-06-04T05:33:03.622243+00:00 app[web.1]: 2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
2020-06-04T05:33:03.622243+00:00 app[web.1]: 3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
2020-06-04T05:33:03.622244+00:00 app[web.1]: 4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
2020-06-04T05:33:03.622244+00:00 app[web.1]: Your manifest contains:
2020-06-04T05:33:03.622245+00:00 app[web.1]: {
2020-06-04T05:33:03.622245+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

How is heroku expected to find about the manifest on heroku. The manifest contains

```
"entrypoints": {

    "admin_unify_style": {
        "css": [
            "/packs/css/admin_unify_style-c2ad729a.css"
        ],
        "js": [
            "/packs/js/admin_unify_style-62270c86710162620f91.js"
        ],
        "js.map": [
            "/packs/js/admin_unify_style-62270c86710162620f91.js.map"
        ]
```

Update 1:
It is working in production env outside of heroku and without assets on cloudfront

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short - the manifest should be on heroku, while the assets could be on s3

#### Here is how I got it working - Heroku, S3, Cloudfront, Webpacker, Rails 6, Sprockets.

1. Assets are precompiled and uploaded to s3. public/assets and public/packs are ignored from the repo.

```
public/assets/*
!public/assets/.sprockets-manifest*
public/packs/*
!public/packs/manifest.json*
```

But as you could see the manifest are not.

2. Cloudfront is configured for production with

```
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://blabla.cloudfront.net"
```

3. public/assets and public/fonts are synced on s3 with a s3cmd command. Custom script.
4. After the are synced to s3 we are commiting the manifests

```
if git ls-files -m | grep "public/assets/.sprockets-manifest\|public/packs/manifest.json*"; then
  git add --all public/assets/.sprockets-manifest* -f
  git add --all public/packs/manifest.json* -f
  git commit -m "Autocompiling assets from jenkins"
  git push
fi
```

In this way we only have the two manifests in the repo with all the assets on S3. 
5. Push to heroku and it works. For now, like charm